# PHP dynamically generated hit counter

Tags: php, html

I am a total PHP novice and am trying to write what I think is a pretty simple script. This is the code I have so far:

**HTML / PHP**

```
<?php

$hits = file_get_contents('hits.txt');
 ++$hits;
file_put_contents('hits.txt', $hits);
echo $hits;

$url = $_GET['w'];
?>

<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>"></iframe>

<p>
<?php echo $hits; ?>
</p>
```

The result is a page with an iframe and a hit counter.

The problem with this script is that if the variable `$url` changes, the hit counter does not. My goal would be that if I visited `http://www.website.com/index.php?w=blue.html` I would get a different counter than if I visited `http://www.website.com/index.php?w=yellow.html`.

EDIT: I should add that this script is designed to accept any URL. I realize this complicates things significantly. My ultimate goal would be that if the counter didn't already exist for that particular URL, it would be generated on the fly.

Comment: Well currently, you're accessing one file and writing and reading to and from it. How do you expect your current code to know to only show hits for one URL?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, but my thought was I could use the value of `$url` to create unique variables to track different counters within hits.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code saves the hit points for every page to the same file as a simple string.

You have a number of options. Here's one that would work if you prefer to stick with text files instead of databases.

You could take the URL in, hash it, and save the counter for that page in a hash-named text file.

Something like

```
if( isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET['W']) ){
$url = md5($_GET['w']);
$hits = file_get_contents('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt');
$hits++;
file_put_contents('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt', $hits);
}
```

and then later you could echo out the hits under that or pull the hits in on another script and echo like that.

If you need it to create new ones on the fly, you could add something like

```
if(!is_file('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt')){
$fh= fopen('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fh, '1');
fclose($fh);
}
```

**NOTE**
This could end up creating a ton of tiny text files, though. So be aware. If you are worried about that, you would really need to look into a database or read in a text file line by line to find the same hash.

**TO IMPLEMENT**
Replace the top part of your code within the `<?php ?>` with the following:

```
if( isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET['W']) ){
    $url = md5($_GET['w']);
    if(!is_file('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt')){
        $fh= fopen('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fh, '1');
        fclose($fh);
    }else{
        $hits = file_get_contents('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt');
        $hits++;
        file_put_contents('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt', $hits);
    }
}
```

This will take the page name in, hash it, check to see if /hit_counters/THEHASH.txt exists, and create it if not or add +1 to it otherwise. A hash is sort of like encryption, but not really. It will change your $_get['w'] into a longer random-looking string.

Comment: I don't mind having a ton of txt files. This is just a proof-of-concept exercise. This looks promising, but I am not entirely sure how it would integrate into my code. Sorry to be such a layman, but would you mind showing me how that would work?

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong: http://www.colindunn.com/prints/index.php

And my code: http://codepad.org/UGC2guKl

Comment: replace` $url = $_GET['W']` with `$url = $_GET['w']` (those variables are case sensitive) 

And you'll need to replace your `src='$url'` with `src='$_GET['w']'` later on in the page. Depending on your use though, that could turn out to be dangerous. Might need to do something like `src='url_encode($_GET['w'])'`.

Comment: Thank you!! This is amazing. The only remaining issue is that when I visit a URL for the first time, I get this warning `Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in [...]/colindunn/prints/index2.php on line 6`

Comment: Sorry, it should be `fwrite($fh,'1');`

The parameters should be switched.

Comment: @joghod I updated your answer accordingly so that future readers don't hit this roadblock. :)

Comment: Thank joghod. I can't tell you how appreciative I am.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the same `hits.txt` file regardless of what `$_GET['w']` is set to. Try putting the `hits.txt` file in a folder like this:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['w'];

$dir = str_replace(".html", "", $url);

$hits = file_get_contents($dir.'/hits.txt');
++$hits;
file_put_contents($dir.'/hits.txt', $hits);
echo $hits;


?>

<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>"></iframe>

<p>
<?php echo $hits; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: That would work if I had a fixed set of pages I was dealing with. But the script is designed to accept any URL, and my goal would be that it would generate new hit counters on the fly

Comment: Ok, I was going to write up a solution to that, but Joghod's answer would work.